# SAS pass through to Oracle to alter table

Tags: oracle, sas, ddl

I am trying to use *SAS pass through facility* to alter an Oracle table and got this error:

> *ORACLE execute error:* `ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option`.

Below is my code. Anybody knows what's wrong with my code? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
PROC SQL;

CONNECT TO oracle (user="myuserid" password="mypswd" path = "mypath") ;

EXECUTE 
(
  ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable
  ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_pk PRIMARY KEY (col_1, col_2, col_3);

) BY oracle;

QUIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `;` before `)  BY oracle;` at the end of *EXECUTE* statement and make :

```
EXECUTE ( ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_pk 
          PRIMARY KEY (col_1, col_2, col_3) ) BY oracle;
```

to suppress the error.